# eval function stop execution

Tags: php, eval

I'm trying to use a `PHPReports` library in my project but I have a problem.

I could find out that execute stop unexpected when it reaches the instruction `eval($sRst)` in `PHPReportMaker.php` at line 275 approx.

I analyzed the contain of `$sRst` and saw, that is a class definition (is a large class to put here).

Is correct defined syntactically, because I though that was a memory trouble I tried increased the `memory_limit` from `128M` to `1024M` in `php.ini` without effect but, I inspected all errors log in apache and nothing about this trouble.

What could be the issue?

I'm using `xammp v1.8.3` in `windows 7`, my IDE is `Netbeans` with `PHP v5.5.6`.

Comment: eval()? Run... run away fast.

Comment: Likely you have security setting that disallow `eval()`.  Any application that uses that should send up a red flag in your mind.

Comment: **`eval()` is `evil`**! :)

Comment: "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question." -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP

Comment: eval() ain't that bad when used properly.

Comment: eval() is __always__ bad, because you can't ever cleanly manage errors from the evalled code; and that's a best case scenario: there are __always__ better ways than eval

Comment: I know the troubles of eval. But it is placed in a library. Finally I found it the problem. This f*** library is a bit old and in some files uses pass by reference variables. So, as Im using PHP v5.5 this feature isn't available. The class stored in $rSt contain this kind of variables. Thanks all for answers!!!